# FPfigure not working

Tags: floats

I am trying to put a figure caption on the following page from the figure. It works fine when I run it on a small document but as soon as I try to run in on my thesis master document through a linked chapter it doesn't work. When I uncomment it the document runs fine. Any idea why the same command works for one and not the other?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[CaptionAfterwards]{fltpage}

\begin{document}

\begin{FPfigure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{Figure.pdf}
\caption{A caption}
\label{Label}
\end{FPfigure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Without an example code that reproduces the problem, the answer (from me at least) is no, I have no idea.

Comment: I have no experience with the `fltpage` package, but I did notice that (a) it was last updated in 1998 and (b) it's not even part of the TeXLive distribution. Rather than tinker with getting a semi-ancient package to work, you may want to look into the capabilities of the `caption` package. E.g., using that package's `\ContinuedFloat` macro, you could (i) define a `figure` environment on one page *without* a `\caption`, insert a page break, and (ii) "resume" said `figure` with a `\ContinuedFloat` instruction; in the second part of the `figure` you'd provide the `\caption` and `\label` info.

Comment: Mico, Could you write an example code that illustrates this?

Cheers

Comment: Jaco: Check the user manual of `caption` package for `\ContinuedFolat`.