# Hypcap giving a "missing \caption" error when used with FPFigure / fltpage

Tags: floats, errors, captions

I'm currently using a package for placing the caption on a separate page, CaptionAfterwards, and the hypcap package gives me the following error:

*"Package hypcap Error: You have forgotten to use \caption."*

I've tried reading and applying answers to a [similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45935/hypcap-not-working-with-custom-figure-environment), but without any success.

How do I get these packages to work together nicely? I have a number of large, full-page figures which need to have captions on the following page. Additionally, the captions need to be recognized as such in order to be correctly included in the *list of figures*.

Is there an alternative method? The [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/181399/fpfigure-not-working) on this answer suggests to me that the [fltpage package](http://ctan.org/pkg/fltpage) is a poor choice, while others [partly recommend it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53315/how-to-put-large-figure-caption-on-separate-page-from-the-figure).

Below is my minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{report}

% PDF hyperlinks
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[figure,table]{hypcap}

\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{Droid Serif}

%Figures
\usepackage[CaptionAfterwards]{fltpage}


\begin{document}

This is an example which returns:

"Package hypcap Error: You have forgotten to use \textbackslash caption."

\begin{FPfigure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=4.5in]{Temp_figure.png}
    \caption[Short caption for TOC]{Long caption to describe figure}
    \label{figure1}
\end{FPfigure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Package `hypcap` is outdated.  Better use package `caption` with option `hypcap=true`.

Please test the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{report}

\usepackage{graphicx}

% PDF hyperlinks
\usepackage[hypcap=true]{caption}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
%\usepackage[figure,table]{hypcap}

\usepackage{textcomp}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{Droid Serif}

%Figures
\usepackage[CaptionAfterwards]{fltpage}


\begin{document}

This is an example which returns:

"Package hypcap Error: You have forgotten to use \textbackslash caption."

\begin{FPfigure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=4.5in]{example-image-a}
    \caption[Short caption for TOC]{Long caption to describe figure}
    \label{figure1}
\end{FPfigure}

\end{document}
```

Remark: I used picture `example-image-a`, part of package `mwe`that must be installed but not called.

Comment: The change that you proposed worked exactly as hoped, with the caption displayed both in my MWE example and in the larger original document. Thank you.